# Security Review-Requirements

Tags: security-review, zap-scanner, handshake-failure

We submitted for security review yesterday,and they have sent a mail saying few reports are not being uploaded like ZAP and also few **Composite piece(s) of your application was not accessible**

**What does that composite pieces mean**?We have uploaded a document of credentials and components along with endpoint URL of our web service and their authentication credentials.we have also uploaded a PPT about our product along with that..what does that composite pieces refer to actually?

**ZAP Scanner Clarification to submit for security Review??:**
Since our product involves web services,when trying to scan our Endpoint URL alone directly in ZAP.It says Handshake failure??How are we supposed to resolve that??